# How to calculate square root of integer in Ada

Tags: ada

Hi I am a beginner in learning Ada. Can someone please tell me how to calculate square root of integers in Ada and do we have to add any packages for it?

Comment: Are you using any resources for learning Ada? What do they say about math?

Answer (score 1):

When you look in the [index of the reference manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-0-5.html), the trick is to know that even Ada shortens the name of the function to `Sqrt`.

The Ada standard library doesn't include a square root function for integer types, so you will have to either:

- Convert your integer to a floating point type, use the standard library, and then convert back,

or

- Write your own integer square root function.